# Interperate Jacobian Determinant - Stability of Equilibriums

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

In my SIR model, I have the following Jacobian Matrix

\begin{align*} J =\begin{bmatrix} -\alpha I & -\alpha S & \zeta & 0 \\  \alpha I & \alpha S - \beta - \rho & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta & -\zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \rho &  0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}

Now I have two equilibriums given by the following:

> **Disease-Free Equilibrium**
>
> Consider the case when $I=0$:
>   $$(\bar{S},\bar{I},\bar{R},\bar{D}) = (N,0,0,0)$$
>   The Jacobian at the Disease-Free Equilibrium is thus
>   \begin{align*}J_1(N,0,0,0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -\alpha N & \zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha N - \beta - \rho & 0 &0 \\ 0 & \beta & -\zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \rho & 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} \end{align*}
>
> We have $\det(J_1 - \lambda \textbf{I} ) = \lambda ^2 (\zeta +\lambda ) (-\text{$\alpha $N}+\beta +\lambda +\rho )$

EDIT:

Here are the ODE's

> $$\frac{dS}{dt} =-\alpha SI + \zeta R$$
>   $$\frac{dI}{dt} = \alpha SI - \beta I - \rho I$$
>   $$\frac{dR}{dt} = \beta I - \zeta R$$
>   $$\frac{dD}{dt} = \rho I$$
>
> where
>
> 1. $\alpha = $ rate at which susceptibles become infected
> 2. $\beta = $ rate at which infected becomes recovered
> 3. $\zeta = $ rate at which members of recovery become susceptible again
> 4. $\rho = $ rate at which infected pass away

Comment: Just an observation: In both cases, $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue, hence the equilibrium is not hyperbolic, and thus you wouldn't be able to say that the equilibrium is stable even if you knew that all the other eigenvalues had negative real parts.

Comment: @HansLundmark - Thank you!! :) :) Are there any other "tests" I can perform to test the stability of equilibriums in the SIR model? This is my first time setting up a model and I am teaching it myself, so any advice will be much appreciated :)

Comment: That's a big question... Once you leave the linear analysis, you'll have to use your imagination to come up with something else. If you believe that the equilibrium is stable, perhaps the first thing to look for is a Lyapunov function?

Comment: @HansLundmark do you think making use of phase planes will be of any help? I will edit the question in a little while and include the system of ODE's that I have since that might give a better picture :)

Comment: Well, "phase plane" will be "4-dimensional phase space" in this case, so it might be a little hard to draw a picture...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19050/discussion-between-dillon-and-hans-lundmark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've factored the characteristic polynomial of $J_1$, so you know the eigenvalues: $0, 0, -\zeta, N \alpha - \beta - \rho$.  $-\zeta < 0$, but 
$N \alpha - \beta - \rho$ could go either way.  The criterion for the disease to "take off", i.e. for a small number of infectives to start an epidemic, is
$N \alpha - \beta - \rho > 0$ (the zero eigenvalues are just associated with
eigenvectors $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ which just increase the population of
susceptibles or deceased).

Your Doomsday scenario is **not** an equilibrium.  It is easy to see that there are no equilibria where $I > 0$, because $D$ will be increasing as long as $I > 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! :). I really appreciate it :). So this system only has the one equilibrium? :)

Comment: No, the equilibria are $I=0, R=0$ with $S$ and $D$ arbitrary.